# Struct error in C "incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [5]' [-Wint-conversion]"

Tags: c, struct

learning C for my data structures and algorithms class. I am trying to make a basic struct for a drivers license but I keep getting this error whenever I go to compile it.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct driversLiscence{
    char name;
    int dob;
    int liscenceNum; 
};

int main(){
    struct driversLiscence Matt;
    Matt.name = "Matt";
    Matt.dob = 11031997;
    Matt.liscenceNum = 112040190;
    printf("Name is: %c\n",Matt.name);
    printf("DOB is: %d\n",Matt.dob);
    printf("Liscence number is: %d",Matt.liscenceNum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `char` does not have an assigned buffer/array size.  Perhaps try `char name[10]`. And the `printf` formatter should be `%s` rather than `%c`.

Comment: A `char` is considered a **single** character, you are assigning a whole `string`. Change `name` to either a `char *` or an array of static size and use a string copy function. Also adjust the `printf()` format specifier, `%c` will print a single a character, `%s` will print a null terminated string.

Comment: Side note, consider saving the license number as a string instead of int, what happens if the format is like this `00012354`?

Comment: ... or exceeds `1 << 31`?  Or formatted `A123456789`?  The list goes on.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct driversLiscence{
    char name;
```

`name` is a single character. Unless you live in a very small society where people have single-letter names, you will need a bit more characters to store the person's name.

You want:

```
struct driversLiscence{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
```

And your `name` can be `MAX_NAME_LENGTH - 1` characters long.

But if you compile your code you will have another problem as arrays can't be assigned. You need to copy the name into this struct member.

```
    strcpy(Matt.name, "Matt");
```

You can also declare `name` as a pointer to `char` but I think it is a bit to early for you and it introduces new requirements and problems.